# auto scroll for UITextView using swift (IOS app)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I cant seem to find a right solution to autoscroll `UITextView` using **Swift**.

For my app I am receiving constant data from BT, and I am updating it on a `UITextView`. However, when the `UITextView` will reach the latest updated line, I would have to manually scroll.

What I'm trying to achieve is to keep the last added line to the `UITextView` visible. (using swift)

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now so all I can do is you could try using a timer and increase the `contentOffset`. This will make it auto scroll. And when you reached the end, you can invalidate the timer to stop the scroll.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will scroll to the bottom of a `UITextView`, with an animation:

```
let range = NSMakeRange(textView.text.characters.count - 1, 0)
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 update for @SwiftArchitect answer:

```
let range = NSRange(location: textView.text.count - 1, length: 0)
textView.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also set contentOffset:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: (textView.contentSize.height - textView.bounds.height))
textView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
```

It will scroll to the bottom.