# Swift: Scroll a UITextView horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to display selected contacts on a label which could be scrolled like in Snapchat. After going through lot of questions on stackoverflow I have used Textview since it is scrollable.

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedContactsDisplay: UITextView!
selectedContactsDisplay.delegate = self
selectedContactsDisplay.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColor()     
selectedContactsDisplay.textColor = UIColor.white
selectedContactsDisplay.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
selectedContactsDisplay.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingHead

let stringOne = selectedContactName.joined(separator: ",")
selectedContactsDisplay.text = stringOne

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

But, the horizontal scrolling is still not possible. Can someone help me on how can the enable the scrolling.

Comment: you can't scroll horizontally in `UITextView`!

Comment: @Ananth collection view and table view are also scrollable.And subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: What you can do is to enable autoScroll. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35018590/6203030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not scroll horizontally in `UITextView`. For solution you can take a `UIScrollView` which can scroll horizontally and can add label or textfield in to it and increase width of that label according to your content! Proper constraint should be set!

Comment: Thank you so much. I have managed to do it the way you suggested.

Comment: I have a question. Now, How do I scroll to the end of the label text. Right now, even when I add new data, It is only showing the beginning part of the text.

Comment: you need to calculate your label's width and set frame of label to that width!

Comment: Does UILabel accept input? Can the user type in UILabel and add and change the text content?

Answer (score 3):

You can not scroll in a TextView by yourself, what you can do is to enable autoScroll:

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedContactsDisplay: UITextView!
selectedContactsDisplay.delegate = self
selectedContactsDisplay.backgroundColor = UIColor.appColor()     
selectedContactsDisplay.textColor = UIColor.white
selectedContactsDisplay.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
selectedContactsDisplay.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingHead


let stringOne = selectedContactName.joined(separator: ",")
selectedContactsDisplay.text = stringOne

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.resignFirstResponder()
let range = NSMakeRange(selectedContactsDisplay.text.characters.count - 1, 0)
selectedContactsDisplay.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
}
```