# iOS: Horizontal scroll and single line in TextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

Is it possible to make TextView Single Line and horizontal scroll in Swift or Storyboard?

Like the following...

```
Single Line Single Line Single LineSingle LineSingle Line　Single Line　Single LineSingle LineSingle LineSingle LineSingle Line　Single Line
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find a good solution. When I write a lot in TextView, it always expands vertically. I want to make it expand horizontally instead.

Comment: are you working with SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: @witekbobrowski UIKit

Comment: is UITextField not suitable for your use case?

Comment: I guess... I tried Label and Text Field. Neither doesn't work well

Comment: And to be clear, you need it to be editable?

Comment: if not, you can use UILabel and wrap it inside UIScrollView. make sure to set `numberOfLines` on UILabel to 1

Comment: @witekbobrowski Yes. Also no ellipsis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift: Scroll a UITextView horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322541/swift-scroll-a-uitextview-horizontally)

Comment: Thank, so I can't do horizontal scroll...

Comment: not directly, you can try to implement it by wrapping text view in UIScrollView, but it will probably take some effort to manage the layout properly

Comment: yeah... Thanks tho!

Comment: if you are interesting in allowing only 1 line of text you can use `UITextField` which will scroll horizontally

Comment: Oh nice. I'll check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226525/discussion-between-witek-bobrowski-and-pytan).